# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Azure Databricks execution error while parallelizing on pandas dataframe. The code is able to create RDD but breaks at the time of performing `.collect()`

setup:

```
import pandas as pd
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 

def testfn(i):
  return my_df.iloc[i]
test_var=sc.parallelize([0,1,2],50).map(testfn).collect()
print (test_var)
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2941072546245585> in <module>
      1 def testfn(i):
      2   return my_df.iloc[i]
----> 3 test_var=sc.parallelize([0,1,2],50).map(testfn).collect()
      4 print (test_var)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    901         # Default path used in OSS Spark / for non-credential passthrough clusters:
    902         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 903             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    904         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    905 

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    125     def deco(*a, **kw):
    126         try:
--> 127             return f(*a, **kw)
    128         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    129             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 16 in stage 3845.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 16.3 in stage 3845.0 : org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'', from <command-2941072546245585>, line 2. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 654, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 646, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 279, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 109, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<command-2941072546245585>", line 2, in testfn
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1767, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2137, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2060, in _validate_integer
    len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 424, in _get_axis
    return getattr(self, name)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5270, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 63, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__get__
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5270, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'
```

Version details:

spark: '3.0.0'
python:3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22)
[GCC 7.3.0]

Comment: I am facing the same issue too. Following this question.

Comment: are you running it via databricks-connect? What is the runtime version that you're using? How do you install Pandas?

Answer (score 12):

I've seen such error when driver & executors had different version of Pandas installed.  In my case it was driver with Pandas 1.1.0 (via databricks-connect), and executors were on Databricks Runtime 7.3 with Pandas 1.0.1.   Pandas 1.1.0 has a big change in internals, so the code sent by the driver to executors is broken.   You need to check that your executors and driver have the same version of the Pandas (you can find version of the Pandas used by Databricks Runtimes in the [release notes](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/releases.html)).  You can use the [following script](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/dbconnect-package-versions-check) to compare version of the Python libraries on executors & driver.

Comment: I've updated the link in the answer

Answer (score 3):

I come across the same question。

i think it is due to  pandas version difference。

i solved this bug by updating my pandas version from 1.0.1 to 1.0.5

Comment: if you check another answer it's saying that it's because of Pandas version difference :-)